# How do we translate "to expect", in the sense of "the author expects the reader is familiar with Chinese culture"?

Tags: translation, word-choice

I find myself having trouble translating this version of the English word "expect":

> The author **expects** the reader is familiar with Chinese culture.
> I **expect** that you have completed your homework.
> Experts **expect** we will never solve this problem.
> You can **expect** professionalism from our employees.

This version of "expect" doesn't mean "anticipate" nor "look forward to"; it's used to state a presumption.  It means something like "presume" or "suppose":

> to expect or assume especially with confidence
> <sub>*presume*, [Merrium-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presume)</sub>
>
> to believe or assume as true; take for granted:  *It is supposed that his death was an accident.*
> <sub>*suppose*, [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/suppose)</sub>

When I've asked Chinese teachers about this, I feel like they don't understand this specific word usage, suggesting [期待](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%9C%9F%E5%BE%85) ("to look forward to / to await / expectation").

**Question**: How do we translate "to expect", in the sense of "the author expects the reader is familiar with Chinese culture"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The author expects the reader is familiar with Chinese culture.

Expect in this context refers to [預期](https://cantoneseplus.com/word/8718) (expect; assume)

> Google Translate: 作者預期他的读者是熟悉中国文化的。 --> the author expects his readers to be familiar with Chinese culture

The author's assumption was based on logical deduction. Only people familiar with Chinese culture would be interested in reading his book and capable of understanding the context

Comment: Honestly I'm a bit puzzled that you frequently quote Google Translate. Even though the translation quality has definitely improved in recent years, it often produces weird results. Do you think its accuracy is that much consistent?

Comment: @blackgreen I only quote Google Translate when the result is accurate. The reason I use it is to check if my translation from English to Chinese can be translated back to English by Google. If Google Translate can understand my Chinese sentence correctly, so can a non-native learner.

Comment: I do not see Google Translate as a reliable reference, I see it as a simplicity test tool

Answer (score 0):

The author expects the reader is familiar with Chinese culture.
作者期盼读者能熟悉中国文化。